# Equalize height of two/more child div of two/more different parent using CSS

Tags: html, css, less

We have div's in separate parent like parent 1 and parent 2 as shown in below image.
We want to make height of both child div's are same by using CSS.
Something like child of Parent 2 should take height of child of Parent 1 or wise-versa.

[image]

We already have JS code to do equalization but it was failed in some cases, where some div's are hidden with their parents. So in that case the highest height of children are not able to fetch and assign to visible child div's.

Comment: What HTML are you working with? What CSS, or JavaScript? What are the edge-cases that are causing trouble? Where's your "*[mcve]*" code?

Comment: this will be possibile in CSS when subgrids will be widely implemented 
 — https://ishadeed.com/article/learn-css-subgrid/

Comment: Hi @FabrizioCalderan, thank you for your valuable suggestion but subgrid supported by Firefox only.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid#browser_compatibility